# Elasticsearch - search fields matching one or more terms

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

Let's say I have a scenario where a product catalog is indexed in Elasticsearch. The index mapping has a number of fields: brand, name, category, color, description.

Given the search text "samsung smartphone black" I would like to know for each term the matching fields with the number of matches.

I would like to get back something like this:

```
samsung = brand (500), description (600)

smartphone = category (2300), name (356), description (900) 

black = name (167), color (1245), description (800)
```

Is there any ES query to get this information?

Comment: I really don't understand the -1 vote on the question. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

A query that matches through several fields can be done with a [Multi Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), but the kind of response you are looking for is not offered by any query as far as I know.

Also, doing this kind of job at your application logic level doesn't sound performant (to start with it's full-text search, so it makes it even more difficult).

Maybe you could do separate Match Queries in each target field, and then compare the results.